# JPA join query not working

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I am trying to use JOIN with JPA. This is my JPA query:

```
SELECT o FROM Assessment AS o 
INNER JOIN AssessmentText at 
WHERE o = at.assessment 
AND at.localeCode = :localeCode
```

The relation from the `Assessment` to `AssessmentText` is `OneToMany`.

When I am executing this query I am getting:

```
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: 
    Encountered "INNER JOIN AssessmentText at" at character 31, 
    but expected: [".", "FETCH", "INNER", "JOIN", "LEFT", <IDENTIFIER>].
```

I am using JPA implementation: OpenJPA 2.2.1 with MySQL database.

Why do I get this error and how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to eager fetch AssessmentText, you can do this (assument Assessment has a member called assessmentText):

```
SELECT o FROM Assessment AS o LEFT JOIN FETCH o.assessmentText WHERE o.assessmentText.localeCode = :localeCode
```

Comment: In this query, where the AssessmentText goes?

Comment: sorry, o.assessment should be replaced by the name of the assessmentText field. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `ON` in your query It should be something like

`SELECT o FROM Assessment AS o INNER JOIN AssessmentText at ON o = at.assessment WHERE at.localeCode = :localeCode`

Comment: can you use something like o.id from assesment to comapir with FK in AssesmentText id? 
`SELECT o FROM Assessment AS o INNER JOIN AssessmentText at ON o.id = at.assessment.oid WHERE at.localeCode = :localeCode`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the relationship from Assessment to AssessmentText was - it needs to be used in the join declaration.

The query you do have shows a relationship from AssessmentText to Assessment which can be used if you refactor the query slightly:

```
SELECT at.assessment FROM AssessmentText at WHERE at.localeCode = :localeCode
```

Answer (score 0):

Have in mind you should create your query in the following way:

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(queryString);
```

Not `em.createNativeQuery` (if you were doing it so).